# Proxifier like software on Unix?

Tags: proxy, software-rec

Having some pleasant time with Proxifier, I just wonder if that kind of software is feasible under Unix/Linux?

Is it easy to start a project like that, or are there existing projects available? Are they nearly as good as Proxifier (capture all TCP/IP packages and forward them through the proxy)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try [ProxyChains](http://sourceforge.net/projects/proxychains) and [Tor](http://www.torproject.org)

Comment: I don't see why you include tor. If I understend the question it is about proxifing the software (otherwise - good answer).

Comment: Tor shouldn't be included. Though it gets the job done, it's not meant for purposes like this.

Answer (score 0):

There is [tproxy](http://freshmeat.net/projects/tproxy/). Alternativly you can use [SocksTun](http://code.google.com/p/socks-tun/) + iptables if you cannot control preload veriables.

Answer (score 0):

## Proxifier like solution for linux:

As of 2019 there is no bundled application that does all what proxifier does and the developer of proxifier is not currently willing to port the application to linux instead you can use different applications for each proxifier feature, i am working on this to bundle all of it on a single application but the project outcome is a little far away. here are the different solutions for each required feature:

- **Block network for an application**

  [Here is](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/454767/120919) a detailed list of solutions for this purpose
- **Route by ip**

  Linux [routing table](http://linux-ip.net/linux-ip/routing-tables.html) can be used to add rules to the routing table and thus route ip/ip-range
- **Route by domain**

  A combination of a sniproxy plus a dns server can do the job (this also support socks and can be be setup easily) [SNI-SSL-Proxy](https://github.com/Intika-Linux-Proxy/SNI-SSL-Proxy) and [Unbound](https://www.nlnetlabs.nl/projects/unbound/about/) ([on github](https://github.com/NLnetLabs/unbound))
- **Route by application (proxy)**

  [Proxybound](https://github.com/Intika-Linux-Proxy/Proxybound) can do the job
- **Route by application (interfaces)**

  [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/498140/120919) enumerate the different solutions for that purpose.
- **Watch and monitor network traffic**

  [Network-Watcher](https://github.com/Intika-Linux-Network/Network-Watcher) or [Watcher-TCP-View](https://github.com/Intika-Linux-Network/Network-Watcher-TCP-View) will do the job