# Is there a command like `time` that monitors the network traffic of commands?

Tags: bash, networking, process-management, wireshark, ss

I can use the time command to measure the time some command takes:

```
time node -e ""
node -e ""  0.06s user 0.01s system 92% cpu 0.076 total
```

Is there a similar way to measure a command's network traffic (the bandwidth it used, the hosts it sent requests to, etc)? What is the best solution for this use case?

Comment: Related - duplicate? https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/375387/117549

Comment: Read `man time`. Will the socket reads/writes (`%r`, `%s`) help?

Comment: Tracking the hosts accesses would require capturing outgoing network  packets. Not easy.

Comment: @waltinator I don't see those flags on macOS's time.

Comment: this can be considered as a  no-sense because network traffic will vary again and again doing routing doing retries & so on so measurement by "time" is just a very bad indicator ; you might prefer a traffic analysis tool or a monitor tool or trying to work around asynchronously as @waltinator said from capturing output. at worst just keep on the ping or traceroute commands