# Limit network interface to specific commands vice versa

Tags: network-interface, internet, network-namespaces

I'm using this tutorial: [Bind unix program to specific network interface](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210982/bind-unix-program-to-specific-network-interface)

Assume that $NS and $IN is set properly

**My problem**
I have two network interfaces and one of them has data limits and I don't want anything other than specific commands to access it. But when I try to use it with "ip netns exec $NS {command}" this command <strike>can't reach internet</strike> can connect to IP addresses but can't resolve hosts

**Steps I took**

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/netns/$NS
sudo sh -c "echo \"nameserver 8.8.8.8\" >> /etc/netns/$NS/resolv.conf"
curl <ip> // OK
curl <site> // OK
sudo ip netns add $NS
sudo ip link set $IN netns $NS
sudo ip netns exec $NS ip link set lo up
sudo ip netns exec $NS ip link set $IN up
sudo ip netns exec $NS dhclient $IN
sudo ip netns exec $NS curl <ip> // OK
sudo ip netns exec $NS curl <site> // Could not resolve host: <site>
```

**Notes**

- Interface type is ethernet
- netns ip route (ip netns exec $NS ip route) seems to be in order,
  default route points towards the IP $IN has
- Commands in given steps except for the last command execute without error

Comment: Then run with specific user, and you can limit the traffic for only one user.

Comment: I updated my question, apparently this is a nameserver issue