Send UDP data from one NIC and receive on another NIC on same machine
I have multiple NIC's on my Ubuntu machine.
$ ifconfig
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:caff:fe8e:4751  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:ca:8e:47:51  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 765284  bytes 41062277 (41.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1184197  bytes 5763037228 (5.7 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    
eno1np0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.10.100.105  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.10.100.255
        ether 3c:ec:ef:74:3b:16  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 31185342  bytes 31349645842 (31.3 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7674137  bytes 1643490885 (1.6 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    
eno2np1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 3c:ec:ef:74:3b:17  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    
enp175s0f0np0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.16.0.10  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.16.255.255
        ether 1c:34:da:7e:65:de  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 214905696  bytes 268542904796 (268.5 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 75363  bytes 11878888 (11.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    
enp175s0f1np1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.16.0.11  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.16.255.255
        ether 1c:34:da:7e:65:df  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 36352647  bytes 40206354758 (40.2 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 283164  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 998  bytes 114081 (114.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 3819602  bytes 764575236 (764.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3819602  bytes 764575236 (764.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

I can send and receive datagrams via UDP sockets. I am using code like this
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets under UDP client server examples.
My server is running on enp175s0f1np1 172.16.0.11
I only see my RX increment on enp175s0f1np1 when I do 'watch -n,1 ifconfig'
The TX (on any NIC) does not increment. Not sure why, I am receiving data just fine.
I think it is using the same NIC enp175s0f1np1 for TX and RX.
How can I make it do TX from the other NIC enp175s0f0np0 172.16.0.10?
The SO_BINDTODEVICE seems to be for server sockets, as shown here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/648721/583986
Will it work for client socket as well?
Also any idea why the TX won't increment when I am receiving data?

It's sometimes useful to consider that the IP address belongs to the machine rather than the NIC. When you send a datagram from the machine to itself there's no need for it actually to be transmitted and received through a physical NIC. The required endgame, that you've sent a packet to yourself, can be achieved far more simply in software. Similar shortcuts can apply when you have two NICs on the same subnet

True.
I am setting up a test rig and I need the messages out from one NIC, and into the other NIC. I need to do this on the same machine

It's tricky to get traffics destined at one of the host's own IP "out" because local routes are the first ones matched against, due to the fact that the ip rule that look up their table has the highest precedence (lowest possible priority value 0). On the other hand, local routes are also what makes a host consider certain traffics are for itself (so that they won't be L3 forwarded out).

To do external loopback you can setup 2 namespaces and put one interface in each namespace, then run each program within one namespace, and the kernel will not see that there is an internal shortcut. See this answer.

meuh: If you change your comment to answer , I can accept it

@rosewater I've never actually done this, but if you have and it worked then please post an answer with what you did, and then you can accept it after a delay of 24 hours.
